# Bot can't find provisioning profile though project contains it and its been uploaded to the bot server

Tags: ios, xcode

I've got an app that builds fine when built/archived from within Xcode.

I've set up a bot for the build but when the bot builds its saying for an extension that it requires a provisioning profile with the App Groups feature.

This extension however is configured to use the correct provisioning profile and this profile does have App Groups as a capability - here is the profile set within Xcode for the extension:

[image]

When setting up the bot, in the Signing/Certificates and Profiles section I selected all the profiles and clicked the Upload To Server button.

I additionally manually added the profiles to:

> /Library/Developer/XcodeServer/ProvisioningProfiles

I've turned off the bot server and restarted it.

Any idea why the bot is not detecting the provisioning profile?

(There are absolutely no mistakes with the app / Xcode / the provisioning profiles being mismated - the app can be build within Xcode and published to the app store.
The problem is purely just to do with the Bot build.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply restarting the build machine solved the issue